# Postgres XL add data node to existing cluster

Tags: postgresql, postgres-xl

This is my Postgres XL 9.5 configuration:
GTM
Cordinator 
datanode1
datanode2.
For above mentioned cluster I have created database DB1 which contains table with 50mln rows and distributed by hash between 2 nodes. After that I add 2 more nodes. But when I execute on coordinator Alter table T1 add node (datanode3) I get following exeption

ERROR: Failed to get pooled connections HINT: This may happen because one or more nodes are currently unreachable, either because of node or network failure. Its also possible that the target node may have hit the connection limit or the pooler is configured with low connections. Please check if all nodes are running fine and also review max_connections and max_pool_size configuration parameters.

Max_connections and max_pool_size parameters are fine, when I checked logs on datanode3 and datanode4 I find the coordinatior can't connect to nodes because database DB1 does not exists. If I create new database and tables in it I can distribute them to all nodes. But all operations beside select on DB1 can't complete.
Do you have any suggestion to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually add these nodes to the cluster before trying to point the database to use them?   If not they they do not exist in the cluster to use.  Also did you init and configure those data nodes to know to connect to the coordinators?

See section F.32.12. pgxc_ctl commands
http://files.postgres-xl.org/documentation/pgxc-ctl.html

https://sourceforge.net/p/postgres-xl/mailman/message/32644691/